# If $a^3+b^3=c^3,$ prove that

Tags: inequality, contest-math

If $a,b,c\in\mathbb R^{+},$ such that $a^3+b^3=c^3,$

Prove that   $$a^2+b^2-c^2>6(c-a)(c-b).$$

**Edit**: This question comes from the Indian Mathematical Olympiad, and I have posted below the proof I found.

Comment: This question is missing context. What is the source of the problem? Why do you suspect it is true? What motivation or application makes the problem interesting? Please edit your post to include this kind of information.

Comment: Source:a Math Olympiad

Comment: I  think the question is from Indian Mathematical Olympiad. ( I dont remember the year). Thats the source according to me. And the topic this falls in is the inequality section.

Comment: @KingTut please introduce yourself in a private message. I shall answer u there.

Comment: I don't need your help anymore because I got the answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a^3=c^3-b^3$$
$$\frac{a^2}{(c-b)}=\frac{c^2+cb+b^2}{a}.......(1)$$

Similarly,
$$b^3=c^3-a^3$$
$$\frac{b^2}{(c-a)}=\frac{c^2+ca+a^2}{b}.......(2)$$

We can observe that
$$\frac{a^2}{(c-b)}+\frac{b^2}{(c-a)}=\frac{c(a^2+b^2)-a^3-b^3}{(c-b)(c-a)}=\frac{c(a^2+b^2-c^2)}{(c-b)(c-a)}........(3)$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2),$
$$\frac{a^2}{(c-b)}+\frac{b^2}{(c-a)}=\frac{c^2+cb+b^2}{a}+\frac{c^2+ca+a^2}{b}$$

By AM-GM inequality, $b^2+c^2>2bc$ and $a^2+c^2>2ac$

So,

$$\frac{b^2+c^2+bc}{ac}>\frac{3b}{a}$$

$$\frac{a^2+c^2+ac}{bc}>\frac{3a}{b}$$

Adding,

$$\frac{c(a^2+b^2-c^2)}{(c-b)(c-a)}>3(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a})..........[from(3)]$$
Again by AM-GM inequality, $a^2+b^2>2ab$
$$\frac{c(a^2+b^2-c^2)}{(c-b)(c-a)}>3(2)$$
$$a^2+b^2-c^2>6(c-b)(c-a)$$